# AngularFireStorage - How to set the downloadURL for a list of items

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, angularfire2

I'm querying a collection where each of the documents inside have an associated image. The angularfirestorage snippet that I'm using works well in setting one image, however, when I have a list, they all end up with the same image.

How do I make sure that each image from each document has the correct binding in the HTML?

```
myPhoto: Observable<string | null>;
...
   this.albums = this.albumCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data();
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        var image = myPhoto;
        const ref = this.storage.ref(image);
        this.myPhoto = ref.getDownloadURL();
        return { id, ...data };
      }))
    );



<div [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + (myPhoto | async)  + ')'}"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

Instead of

```
this.myPhoto = ref.getDownloadURL();
```

I use:

```
data.myPhoto = ref.getDownloadURL();
```